# Mongoose detect database not ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to detect that the database is not running with Mongoose ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would recommend using the `open` and `error` events to check if you can connect to the database. This is a simple example used in all my projects to double check that I'm connected.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
  console.log('Connected to mongo server.');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Could not connect to mongo server!');
  console.log(err);
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongodb');
```

Comment: Yeah that works better. Just remember to use semicolons ";"
:)

Answer (score 21):

You can tell if mongoose is already connected or not by simply checking

```
mongoose.connection.readyState
0 = no
1 = yes
```

Comment: There are actually 4 different states. In addition to the two mentioned, there is 2="connecting" and 3="disconnecting". See here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-readyState

Answer (score 10):

The straight forward works fine for me:

`mongoose.Connection.STATES.connected === mongoose.connection.readyState`

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking for the constant. This is cleaner than using == 1

Answer (score 4):

Apparently Mongoose it self doesn't throw any exceptions.

So you can use the Mongo DB Native NodeJS Driver:

So here's what you can do:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;

console.log(">> Connecting to mongodb on 127.0.0.1:27017");

var db = new Db('test', new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {}));

db.open(function(err, db) {
    console.log(">> Opening collection test");
    try {
        db.collection('test', function(err, collection) {
            console.log("dropped: ");
            console.dir(collection);
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        if (!db) {
            throw('MongoDB server connection error!');
        }
        else {
            throw err;
        }
    }
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```