# How to check if db exists during mongodb connection using mongoose.connect?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've tried to use mongoose.connect to check if a db exists,

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/notexistdb",function(err){
     if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

The callback doesn't contain error message, so how can I determine whether the database exists or not.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538345/mongoose-detect-database-not-ready

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find out by getting database list.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin;

/// create a connection to the DB    
var connection = mongoose.createConnection(
    'mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database');
connection.on('open', function() {
    // connection established
    new Admin(connection.db).listDatabases(function(err, result) {
        console.log('listDatabases succeeded');
        // database list stored in result.databases
        var allDatabases = result.databases;    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `open` and `error` events to see if you can connect to the database. If you can connect to it, then it exists. If you can't, then it doesn't.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
  console.log('Connected to Mongo server...');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Could not connect to Mongo server...');
  console.log(err);
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/notexistdb',function(err){
 if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: It seems not work for me, no error message is returned. mongoose.connect seems only check whether your app can connect to server say `localhost:27017` rather than checking the existence of a particular database.

Comment: Same here, posted a slightly different question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232183/how-to-check-if-a-database-exists-with-mongoose-createconnection)

Comment: Same issue with me.. it does not check if db exits or not. Any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your answer returned, you need to use the `desync` library.

Install `desync` using `npm i desync`

You can also use the following function in a different file by exporting it.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin;
const deasync = require("deasync");

function checkDatabase (dbName) {
  var check; // we will return this value
  var uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

  // connect with mongoDB
  mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true})
    .then(() => {
      new Admin(mongoose.connection.db).listDatabases((err, result) => {
        var allDatabases = result.databases;
        check = allDatabases.some((database) => database.name === dbName);
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("some error occured");
    });

  // wait while mongoose executes the result
  while (check == null) {
    deasync.runLoopOnce();
  }

  return check; // either true or false
};
```

We need to use `desync` because much of the node's functionalities are asynchronous. To know more: [Click Here - Callback Functions](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks)