# mongoose - empty result but fine in mongo shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble getting results from a mongoose query within my app.  Via the mongo shell i can run
`db.statements.find({"name":"CASH HSBC"})` and get the correct result but when I run the equivalent through the code below
and `console.log()` the response I get `[]` and I don't understand why.

I have a model below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var statementSchema = new Schema({
date : {type:Date, required:true},
name: {type:String, required:true},
amount: {type:Number, required:true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Statement', statementSchema);
```

and then in my the route js I have

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var parseDate = require('../helpers/parseDate');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Statement = require('../models/statement');


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('You need to add a value');
});

router.get('/:vendor?', function(req, res, next) {

var vendorName = req.params.vendor;

Statement.find({name:req.params.vendor}, function(err, doc){
   if (err) {
       console.error('error no entries found');
   }
    console.log(doc);
    res.render('vendor', {
        vendor: vendorName,
        shop:doc
    });
});

});

module.exports = router;
```

the vendor handlebars template doesn't render anything but I'm guessing that's because the value of `doc` is empty.

EDIT: In relation to request in the comments to make a simple query.

If I add the following to my route

```
var db = Statement.find();
console.log(db);
```

I get a large object in console (which does have reference to my collection)

```
Query {
_mongooseOptions: {},
 mongooseCollection:
   NativeCollection {
 collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
 opts: { bufferCommands: true, capped: false },
 name: 'statements',
 collectionName: 'statements',
 conn:
  NativeConnection {
    base: [Object],
    collections: [Object],
    models: [Object],
    config: [Object],
    replica: false,
    hosts: null,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: undefined,
    pass: undefined,
    name: 'finance',
    options: [Object],
    otherDbs: [],
    _readyState: 1,
    _closeCalled: false,
    _hasOpened: true,
    _listening: false,
    db: [Object] },
 queue: [],
 buffer: false,
 emitter:
  EventEmitter {
    domain: null,
    _events: {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined } },
  model:
   { [Function: model]
 hooks: Kareem { _pres: {}, _posts: {} },
 base:
  Mongoose {
    connections: [Object],
    plugins: [],
    models: [Object],
    modelSchemas: [Object],
    options: [Object] },
 modelName: 'Statement',
 model: [Function: model],
 db:
  NativeConnection {
    base: [Object],
    collections: [Object],
    models: [Object],
    config: [Object],
    replica: false,
    hosts: null,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    user: undefined,
    pass: undefined,
    name: 'finance',
    options: [Object],
    otherDbs: [],
    _readyState: 1,
    _closeCalled: false,
    _hasOpened: true,
    _listening: false,
    db: [Object] },
 discriminators: undefined,
 schema:
  Schema {
    obj: [Object],
    paths: [Object],
    subpaths: {},
    virtuals: [Object],
    singleNestedPaths: {},
    nested: {},
    inherits: {},
    callQueue: [Object],
    _indexes: [],
    methods: {},
    statics: {},
    tree: [Object],
    query: {},
    childSchemas: [],
    s: [Object],
    options: [Object],
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
 collection:
  NativeCollection {
    collection: [Object],
    opts: [Object],
    name: 'statements',
    collectionName: 'statements',
    conn: [Object],
    queue: [],
    buffer: false,
    emitter: [Object] },
 Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
 '$__insertMany': [Function],
 insertMany: [Function] },
  schema:
   Schema {
     obj: { date: [Object], name: [Object], amount: [Object] },
 paths:
  { date: [Object],
    name: [Object],
    amount: [Object],
    _id: [Object],
    __v: [Object] },
 subpaths: {},
 virtuals: { id: [Object] },
 singleNestedPaths: {},
 nested: {},
 inherits: {},
 callQueue: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
 _indexes: [],
 methods: {},
 statics: {},
 tree:
  { date: [Object],
    name: [Object],
    amount: [Object],
    _id: [Object],
    id: [Object],
    __v: [Function: Number] },
 query: {},
 childSchemas: [],
 s: { hooks: [Object], kareemHooks: [Object] },
 options:
  { retainKeyOrder: false,
    typeKey: 'type',
    id: true,
    noVirtualId: false,
    _id: true,
    noId: false,
    validateBeforeSave: true,
    read: null,
    shardKey: null,
    autoIndex: null,
    minimize: true,
    discriminatorKey: '__t',
    versionKey: '__v',
    capped: false,
    bufferCommands: true,
    strict: true,
    pluralization: true },
 '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
  op: 'find',
  options: { retainKeyOrder: false },
  _conditions: {},
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection:
   NodeCollection {
 collection:
  NativeCollection {
    collection: [Object],
    opts: [Object],
    name: 'statements',
    collectionName: 'statements',
    conn: [Object],
    queue: [],
    buffer: false,
    emitter: [Object] },
 collectionName: 'statements' },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  _castError: null,
  _count: [Function],
  _execUpdate: [Function],
  _find: [Function],
  _findOne: [Function],
  _findOneAndRemove: [Function],
  _findOneAndUpdate: [Function],
  _replaceOne: [Function],
  _updateMany: [Function],
  _updateOne: [Function] }
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `req.params.vendor`?

Comment: @chridam thanks.  Yes the value of `req.params.vendor` is coming through correctly and I can use that value in a query in mongo shell and get a result.

Comment: And tried hardcoding the value in your find statement i.e. `Statement.find({ name: "CASH HSBC" }, function(err, doc){ ... })`?

Comment: @chridam yep, added that as you say and no change

Comment: Is your mongoose connection fine? Are your other queries working? Some simple query you can write to test it in your route.js. Can you check it?

Comment: @node_saini interesting. If I `console.log('ready state is '+mongoose.connection.readyState);` it prints a 2

However if I add `mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/statement');` nodemon crashes `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

Comment: On the above, I also have a seeding script to import some values into mongo.  it also reports a ready state of 2 but successfully imports the data

Comment: I just added a simple query `var db = Statement.find();
    console.log(db);` and added the object that is returned as an edit to my question.

Comment: @StuartBrown I recommend you go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11545317/4394926) to check if your connection is giving some error or not. Also connection to database should happen like this `Mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/your_db_name');` Hope `statement` is your DB name not collection name. And instead of `console.log(db);` you can check if query is fetching results or not instead of printing the object.

Comment: For people to get more clear picture you can also post your `mongoose.js` code.